# java Runtime.exec to run shell script - cannot open file

Tags: java, shell, runtime.exec

I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to run a shell script from java code.

```
    String[] cmd = {"sh",  "build.sh", "/Path/to my/sh file"};
    try{
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception is:"+e);
    }
```

It gives me the following output in console:

```
sh: Can't open build.sh
```

Am I following some wrong approach here? Cannot make out why his happens.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment here, I have modified the `String[] cmd = {"sh",  "build.sh", "/Path/to my/sh file"};` to `String[] cmd = {"sh",  "/Path/to my/sh file/build.sh", "/Path/to my/sh file"};` . Now the problem is this script need to be executed from a particular path. When I execute this script from command prompt, I first change the directory to that path and execute it. How should I modify this code?

Comment: provide full path of build.sh i.e. path relative to the project folder

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `ProcessBuilder` and set the working directory of the process to the directory where your script actually is:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "script.sh", "whatever",
    "arguments", "go", "here");
pb.directory(new File("/path/to/directory"));
// redirect stdout, stderr, etc
final Process p = pb.start();
```

See the [`ProcessBuilder` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It contains an example of what you can do. `Runtime.exec()` is passé :p

Comment: You're welcome! Learn this class, it is what you MUST use when running programs in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`sh` is unable to find the `build.sh` script. To fix this you can provide the full path to `build.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 String[] cmd = {"sh build.sh", "/Path/to my/shfile"};
```

and better to use ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh build.sh", "/Path/to my/shfile");
```

Comment: This won't help.  You are telling the OS to run an executable with the pathname `/bin/sh build.sh` ... which definitely does NOT exist on any sane UNIX / Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "sh" command is unable to resolving the relative path `"build.sh"` to an absolute path.  The most likely explanation is that `"build.sh"` is not in the current directory when you launch the command.

Assuming that `"/Path/to my/sh file"` string is the path to the `"build.sh"` file, you need to run it like this:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh",  "/Path/to my/sh file/build.sh"};
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    ...
```

(.... or the equivalent using `ProcessBuilder`)

On the other hand, if the `"/Path/to my/sh file"` string is supposed to be an *argument* to the `"build.sh"` script, then you need to run it like this:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "/some/dir/build.sh", "/Path/to my/sh file"};
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

---

@fge's answer gives an alternative approach.  He is *setting* the current directory for the child process before it is launched.  That is the correct solution for your *updated* Question.

Comment: String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "/home/sreekumar/bin/build.sh"}; works. What if I need to execute this from a particular path. Similar to we change directory in terminal first and then execute the script?

Comment: @user1400538 - As I said, fge's Answer address your updated Question.  Read it.

Comment: ok, done and it works, sorry I read the last part of your question later only. thanks.